# Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate

Tags: python, tensorflow, out-of-memory

I know this is recurrent problem and question, and I'm aware of some solutions, specially if this problem occurs during training (reducing batch size, setting gpu option `allow_grouth=True`), but I'm facing this problem when using the *already trained* model to predict an outcome. 
So, I was able to train the model (a Faster RCNN from the [TensorFlow Object Detection Model Zoo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md) with a batch size of 1 -- otherwise I would receive OOM error during training).

To apply the trained model, I load it with the following code:

```
class Model:

    def __init__(self, conf):
        self.threshold = conf["threshold"]
        self.gpu = conf['gpu']
        self.scope = conf['scope']
        self.frozen_inference_graph = conf['frozen_inference_graph']
        self.detection_graph = self.load_model(self.gpu, self.scope, self.frozen_inference_graph)

        gpu_options = tf.GPUOptions(per_process_gpu_memory_fraction=conf['gpu_usage'], allocator_type='BFC')
        self.session = tf.Session(graph=self.detection_graph,
                                  config=tf.ConfigProto(gpu_options=gpu_options,
                                                        log_device_placement=True,
                                                        allow_soft_placement=True)

    def load_model(gpu, scope, frozen_inference_graph):
        detection_graph = tf.Graph()
        with detection_graph.device(gpu):
            with detection_graph.as_default():
                od_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()

                with tf.gfile.GFile(frozen_inference_graph, 'rb') as fid:
                    serialized_graph = fid.read()
                    od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
                    tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name=scope)
                    return detection_graph
```

Where my conf file looks like:

```
{
    "frozen_inference_graph": "/config/plate_detector/faster_rcnn/frozen_inference_graph.pb",
    "gpu": "/gpu:0",
    "gpu_usage": 0.05,
    "threshold": 0.5,
    "scope": "testing"
  }
```

To apply the model, the class `Model` has the following method:

```
    def detect(self, image):
        image_tensor = self.detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name(self.scope + "/image_tensor:0")
        detection_boxes = self.detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name(self.scope + "/detection_boxes:0")
        detection_scores = self.detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name(self.scope + "/detection_scores:0")
        detection_classes = self.detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name(self.scope + "/detection_classes:0")
        num_detections = self.detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name(self.scope + "/num_detections:0")

        height, width = image.shape[:2]
        image_np = image.copy()
        # Expands dimensions since the model expects images to have shape: [1, None, None, 3]
        image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_np, axis=0)
        # Actual detection
        boxes, scores, classes, num = self.session.run(
            [detection_boxes, detection_scores, detection_classes, num_detections],
            feed_dict={image_tensor: image_np_expanded}
        )

        output_dict = dict()
        output_dict["num_dets"] = int(num[0])
        output_dict["classes"] = classes[0].astype(np.uint8)
        output_dict["bboxes"] = boxes[0]
        output_dict["confidences"] = scores[0]

        detections = []
        for i, b in enumerate(output_dict["bboxes"]):
            if output_dict["confidences"][i] >= self.threshold:
                x1 = int(output_dict["bboxes"][i][1] * width)
                y1 = int(output_dict["bboxes"][i][0] * height)
                x2 = int(output_dict["bboxes"][i][3] * width)
                y2 = int(output_dict["bboxes"][i][2] * height)
                label = self.class_mapping.get(output_dict["classes"][i].astype(str))
                confidence = output_dict["confidences"][i]
                detections.append(detection.Detection([x1, y1, x2, y2, confidence, label]))

        # Sort based on x1 to return the right order
        detections = sorted(detections, key=lambda x: x.x1)

        return detections
```

In my `main.py` file, I simply do (pseudo code):

```
model = Model(*path to config*)
images = fetch_images()
for image in images:
    detections = model.detect(image)
    // processing over the detections
```

However, sometimes, in the middle of the process, I get a message such as:

> 2019-10-16 21:42:32.394227: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:314] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 76.56MiB (rounded to 80281600).  Current allocation summary follows.

**This doesn't happens all the time, it seems to happen at random, which I don't understand.**

I've tried using `allow_growth=True`, which causes the error to happens when I load the model, and also `allocator_type='BFC'`, which didn't help (OOM still happens randomly).

`watch -n 1 nvidia-smi` looks like this:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 435.21       Driver Version: 435.21       CUDA Version: 10.1     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Quadro RTX 4000     Off  | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 30%   40C    P0    96W / 125W |   1589MiB /  7979MiB |     83%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

Comment: Did you try setting higher value for 'gpu_usage' which is used as per_process_gpu_memory_fraction? Regarding randomness, BFC although being quite efficient can have some flactuation of memory usage inbetween runs due to different mapping of data into buckets. Another reason might be variable image size if your model allows that

Comment: Yes, I tried, @y.selivonchyk, but it seemed to be useless. The images are captured by a camera, so they all have the same size. Thanks for the tips.